# Sort lists in a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe column which is a collection of lists

```
    a
['a', 'b']
['b', 'a']
['a', 'c']
['c', 'a']
```

I would like to use this list to group by its unique values (['a', 'b'] & ['a', 'c']). However, this generates an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there any way around this. Ideally I would like to sort the values in place and create an additional column of a concatenated string.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: What's your input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also sort values by column.

Example:

```
x = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'a']]
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': Series(x)})
df.a.sort_values()

     a
0   [a, b]
2   [a, c]
1   [b, a]
3   [c, a]
```

However, for what I understand, you want to sort `[b, a]` to `[a, b]`, and `[c, a]` to `[a, c]` and then `set` values in order to get only `[a, b][a, c]`.

i'd recommend use `lambda`

Try:

```
result = df.a.sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
result = DataFrame(result).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It returns:

```
0    [a, b]
1    [a, c]
2    [a, b]
3    [a, c]
```

Then get unique values:

```
newdf = pandas.DataFrame({'a': Series(list(set(result['a'].apply(tuple))))})
newdf.sort_values(by='a')

     a
0   (a, b)
1   (a, c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with a suggestion from a colleague which was t us np.where, such that `df['b'] = np.where(df.a[0] < df.a[1], df.a[0] + df.a[1],
df.a[1] + df.a[0])`. This gives me a sorted column of the unique values.

Comment: You can also use `apply(sorted)` since it's equivalent to `apply(lambda x: sorted(x))`

Answer (score 3):

list are unhashable.  however, tuples are hashable

use

```
df.groupby([df.a.apply(tuple)])
```

***setup***
`df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[list('ab'), list('ba'), list('ac'), list('ca')]))`
***results***
`df.groupby([df.a.apply(tuple)]).size()`

```
a
(a, b)    1
(a, c)    1
(b, a)    1
(c, a)    1
dtype: int64
```